# Can code library be a managed package without exposing internals?

Tags: apex, managed-package

If I want to write a code library as a managed package, I need to expose all methods and classes that are used by it via a global interface. This exposes a large chunk of library code.

How can I write a code library as a managed package that wouldn't expose the internals?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `global` to specific methods and classes (and interfaces) and leave other methods and classes invisible to users of the managed package. Users of the managed package will only get to see the signatures that are marked as `global` and will see no implementation detail at all.

But how much you will need to expose depends on the design of your classes: you may choose to add [facades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to make the set of things you need to make `global` smaller.

Note that once a class or method has been made `global` and the managed package has been released that decision cannot be reversed. So design and plan carefully.